# Get name of key in select

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am trying to populate a select element from JSON, but the JSON is formatted in such a way that the keys hold valuable information. **I do not have control over the data format.**

I am trying to iterate over the JSON and and grab the key names for the top-level objects in the array. The problem is that because it is an object, I can't seem to grab just its name -- Object.keys() does not work within ng-options due to scoping.

I've tried many variations on the following, with no luck.

```
<select ng-model="$ctrl.vals"
        ng-options="val as key for (key, val) in $ctrl.data"
        ng-change="$ctrl.onChange()" name="{{$ctrl.name}}"
        size="{{$ctrl.data.length}}" multiple>
</select>
```

The above returns "0", because it's formatted as 0: [object object]. The closest I have been able to get is [Object Object] returned, but I want the key of that object, and am not sure how to get it.

I have data formatted like this (sample data, not real):

```
{
"Games": [{
    "Name": "Warhammer 40k 8th Edition",
    "Factions": [{
        "Space Marines": {
            "Units": [{
                "Name": "Primaris Space Marine Captain",
                "Number": 1,
                "Cost": -1,
                "Ability": "When captain enters play you win",
                "AddOns": [{
                    "Name": "My AddOn",
                    "Cost": 0,
                    "Text": "Add an extra Captain",
                    "IsSelected": false
                }],
                "Gear": [{
                    "Name": "Frag Grenade",
                    "Cost": 0
                }]

            }]
        }
        }]
    }]
}
```

In the context of the JSON above, I want to pass in Factions and see the text "Space Marines" as an option.
What am I missing?

Comment: You might want to clarify whether the HTML snippet you've included is actually repeated (i.e. does `$ctrl.data` refer to the top-level object snippet you've posted?), as this would influence the way you'd define your selection expressions.

Comment: $ctrl.data is the array that starts with [{"Space Marines":...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `$ctrl.data` in your snippets refers to the `"Factions"` property value as you've written, then the `ng-options` expression you've used isn't compatible (i.e. the `... for (key, value) in ...` form would require `$ctrl.data` to be an object, which it isn't).

Subsequently, you should use the array expression form for `ng-options`, and then you can supply additional functions to rip out the label and model that will be bound when a user selects a particular option.

Here's how you might go about it:

```js
angular
  .module('app', [])
  .controller('ctrl', function () {
    const $ctrl = this;
    $ctrl.modelFor = function (obj) {
      const [key] = Object.keys(obj);
      return key ? obj[key] : null;
    };
    $ctrl.labelFor = function (obj) {
      const [key] = Object.keys(obj);
      return key;
    };
    $ctrl.data = [{
      "Space Marines": {
        "Units": [{
          "Name": "Primaris Space Marine Captain",
          "Number": 1,
          "Cost": -1,
          "Ability": "When captain enters play you win",
          "AddOns": [{
            "Name": "My AddOn",
            "Cost": 0,
            "Text": "Add an extra Captain",
            "IsSelected": false
          }],
          "Gear": [{
            "Name": "Frag Grenade",
            "Cost": 0
          }]
        }]
      }
    }];
  });
```

```html
<div
  ng-app="app"
  ng-controller="ctrl as $ctrl">
  <select
    ng-model="$ctrl.vals"
    ng-options="$ctrl.modelFor(obj) as $ctrl.labelFor(obj) for obj in $ctrl.data"></select>
  <pre>{{ $ctrl.vals }}</pre>
</div>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/angular@1.7.8/angular.min.js"></script>
```

As an aside, your data looks a bit odd. If each item of `$ctrl.data` can have multiple keys, then this approach will arbitrarily select the first one (i.e. ordering isn't guaranteed when iterating over keys).

Answer (score 0):

Transform the data:

```
 $ctrl.mapped = $ctrl.data.map(_ => {
     var entry = Object.entries(_)[0];
     return { key: entry[0], value: entry[1] };
 });
```

Then use it in the HTML:

```
<select ng-model="$ctrl.vals"
        ng-options="item.value as item.key for item in $ctrl.mapped"
        ng-change="$ctrl.onChange()" name="{{$ctrl.name}}"
        size="{{$ctrl.data.length}}" multiple>
</select>
```